# some images missing after implementing RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been working on this issue for what feels like endless hours, but I feel like I'm really close to solving it.

I have stripped my site down to the bare minimum code to troubleshoot this, and I think I have found the line that is causing me trouble, but I just don't know WHY it is causing me trouble. Here is my code as it is now:

```
//display all products
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT products.*, company.company-name FROM products INNER JOIN company ON products.company-id=company.id");
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Error';
            exit();
        }
}
//display one product
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $get_item_info = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT products.*, company.company-name FROM products INNER JOIN company ON products.company-id=company.id WHERE products.id='$id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_item_info);
            if (!$row) {
                echo 'Error';
                exit();
            }
    $company_name = $row['company-name'];
    $model_abbreviation = $row['model-abbreviation'];
    if ($row['model-version'] == NULL) { $image_directory_name = "$company_name/$model_abbreviation/"; } else $image_directory_name = "$company_name/$model_abbreviation (" . $row['model-version'] . ")/";
}

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $group = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $group[ $row['company-name'] ][] = $row;
        }
        foreach ($group as $company_name => $models) {
                foreach ($models as $model) {
                        echo "<a href='$model[id]/'>$model[model-abbreviation]</a>";
                }
    }
}
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $top_thumb = "$image_directory_name" . "top.jpg";
    echo "<img src='$top_thumb'>"; echo '</br>';
            $images = glob($image_directory_name."*_thumb*");
            if (!$images) {
                echo 'No images to display.';
            }
            else {
                foreach ($images as $image) {
                $full = str_replace('thumb','full',$image);
                    echo '<a href="'.$full.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'"></a>';
            }
        }
}
```

So if I use this code in combination with my rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/$ /products/index.php?id=$1
```

And I go to a product page, such as localhost/products/30/

No images display, HOWEVER, in the page source I can see that it is TRYING to display the images (though I get no error from my script, just a blank page), just with the wrong path - it looks like this:

```
<img src='Company Name/Model Name (Model Version)/top.jpg'></br><a href="Company Name/Model Name (Model Version)/A_full.jpg"><img src="Company Name/Model Name (Model Version)/A_thumb.jpg"></a>
```

So the code is working, but the path is wrong. OK.

So I added /products/ to the $image_directory_name variable in this line:

```
if ($row['model-version'] == NULL) { $image_directory_name = "/products/$company_name/$model_abbreviation/"; } else $image_directory_name = "/products/$company_name/$model_abbreviation (" . $row['model-version'] . ")/";
```

This is where it breaks.

The top thumb is fixed and displays, but I get my error when trying to glob() the bottom thumbs - 'No images to display'. And the source doesn't even show as trying to load them anymore.

So. I have gotten really close, I've spent countless hours on this. Anyone got any idea what's going on? Something to do with my $image_directory_name path or the glob() code I'm guessing...I am so mentally desperate to solve this.

edit: additional info: When I go to localhost/products/companyname/productname/ in my browser, I get the Error from the if (!$row) line in my code. But I go to localhost/products/companyname/productname/imagename.jpg, the image loads.

update: I even tried moving all of my images from /products/companyname/productname/

to /images/companyname/productname/

The bottom thumbs still don't show up. Argh.

Comment: what happens when you change your rewrite rule to:
RewriteRule ^products/(\d)/$ /products/index.php?id=$1

Comment: @JonathanCrowe, with that rule I get "The requested URL /products/id/ was not found on this server."

Comment: $id is an integer yes

Comment: sorry, try RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/$ /products/index.php?id=$1

Comment: That works, but the bottom thumbs still do not load, unfortunately. Thank you so much for replying. I'm completely stumped.